# Multi-value parameters in stored procedure return errors when multiple values are passed to them

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0, sql-server-2017

I'm creating a stored procedure that uses two multi-value parameters:

```
@Class AS VARCHAR(5),
@Service AS VARCHAR(5)
(…)    
WHERE B.UTRCLS IN (@Class) AND B.UTSVC IN (@Service)
```

The procedure works fine when both parameters only contain one value. However, when either or both use multiple values, it throws an error.

In report builder the error is the following:

> Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1 (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)

In SQL Server, the error appears as the following (truncated for length):

> Cannot execute the query "SELECT
>   Col1009,Col1010,Col1008,Expr1003,Expr1004 FROM (SELECT
>   Col1009,Tbl1001.UTCSNM Col1008,Col1010,SUM(Col1016)
>   Expr1003,SUM(Col1014) Expr1004 FROM (…)

I don't think I'm doing anything wrong with declaring the parameters. Is this an issue with multi-value parameters in stored procedures?

Comment: `@Class` is defined as a `varchar(5)`; that is never going to hold multiple values. With an SP, if you want to pass multiple values you would (normally) use a user-defined table-value datatype

Comment: Parameters don't work the way you think. Stored Procedure parameters are always single valued. If UTSVC is an int column, and you try to pass in the string '1, 2' for parameter @Service, then SQL Server will simply complain that '1, 2' cannot be converted to a (single) integer value

Comment: There are many tutorials regarding the use of multi-valued parameters in SSRS with a stored procedure source. Behind the scenes, SSRS will create a single string containing a CSV list of the selected values and pass that to your procedure. [One example](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ssrs-report-for-stored-procedure-with-multiple-values-passed)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a dynamic query:

```
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT * FROM yourTable B WHERE B.UTRCLS IN ( +' @Class + ')' +
                  ' AND B.UTSVC IN (' + @Service +' )'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand
```

Comment: Please remove that or people will start writing code open to SQL Injection.

Comment: Is like you said stop give people knife so they don't stab each other. If you know the source is ok Dynamic query are fine.

Comment: I'm not against dynamic SQL. I'm against unsafe dynamic SQL. There's no way to ensure the source is correct. There are many other options to solve this that don't involve the risks of losing the whole server.

Answer (score 0):

The comments on your post are on the right track. Parameters are single valued for the scope of the stored procedure call, not iterated through for sets of parameter values. I think you have 2 options if you want to pass many values into those parameters.

The first is to expand the character length of your parameters and incorporate a delimiter to segment the values. Your stored procedure code would then need to parse these values and do what is needed from there for each. The STRING_SPLIT() function would help you along the way.

The second options is to define a user data type of type table that mirrors the data structure of the multi-values you need to pass in the parameter. In your stored procedure call you would define a variable of this type, fill it with the values and then pass that variable to your stored procedure. Note that these must be set to READ ONLY when doing so.

Link to MSDN for creating user types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017